# Creating Methods that will produce the same result

Tags: java, methods

I'm in a Beginner Java class and I'm confused about using additional methods and using them in another. I think that I have most of my assignment done but I just need help to create the methods. One is to generate the question and the other one is to display the message.

I know that in order to call a method

```
public static test(num1,num2,num3)
```

but in my code, how do I make it so that I call the method and still make it loop correctly?

In the assignment instructions that was given to me, In order to do that, I have to write a method named

```
public static in generateQuestion()
```

and

```
public static void displayMessage(boolean isCorrect)
```

This is my code:

```
//For Random Generator
import java.util.Random;
//Uses a class Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assign6 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Scanner to Obtain Input from CW
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Generate Random Number for Quiz
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        int number1 = 0;
        int number2 = 0;
        int answer = 0;
        //Rolls number from 1-9
        number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(9);
        number2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(9);
        //Question prompt
        System.out.println("How much is " +number1+ " times " +number2+ "? ");
        answer = input.nextInt();
        //If Else While Statements
        if(answer == (number1*number2))
        {
            System.out.println("Good job! You got it right!");
        }
        else
        {
            while (answer !=(number1*number2))
            {
                System.out.println("You got it wrong, try again!");
                answer = input.nextInt();

            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You may need to restructure your code some more. It never prints a success message when they get it right after getting it wrong.

Comment: I think you need to review how methods work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, It's simply a matter of separating the functionality that prints a question and displays the answer into separate methods.  See my edited version of your code below

```
public class Assign6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Scanner to Obtain Input from CW
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Generate Random Number for Quiz
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        int number1 = 0;
        int number2 = 0;
        int answer = 0;
        // Rolls number from 1-9
        number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(9);
        number2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(9);

        displayQuestion("How much is " + number1 + " times " + number2 + "?");

        answer = input.nextInt();
        // If Else While Statements
        if (answer == (number1 * number2))
        {
            displayMessage(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
        else
        {
            while (answer != (number1 * number2))
            {
                displayMessage(Boolean.FALSE);

                answer = input.nextInt();

            }
        }
    }

    public static void displayQuestion(String q)
    {
        System.out.println(q);
    }

    public static void displayMessage(Boolean isCorrect)
    {
        if (isCorrect)
        {
            System.out.println("Good job! You got it right!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You got it wrong, try again!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not showing the error "You got it wrong" message when the answer inputted is wrong anymore.

Comment: I did not debug it for you, I've only addressed the question you actually asked, which was how to implement the requirement to use two methods.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah. That helped me a lot to understand it. Thank you!

Comment: No problemo.  Try using the debugger, it will help you solve any runtime issues step by step.  Eclipse comes with one out of the box that is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have two methods

```
public static void generateQuestion()
```

Which is going to hold the code to generate the random values and output it. It will return void because all it's doing is printing out.

Next you will have

```
public static void displayMessage(boolean isCorrect)
```

which will be called if `if(answer == (number1*number2))` is true with true as the parameter. Otherwise it will still be called, but the parameter passed in will be false. This method will determine if `isCorrect` is true or false, and output the appropriate message.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, I have a solution that might be a little stupid but will work for your assignment.
If you make `generateQuestion` that makes two random ints, prints the question and returns their multiple (answer).
And `displayMessgae` that prints "Good job! You got it right!" if `isCorrect` is `true` and "You got it wrong, try again!" else,

you can call `generateQuestion`, then get an answer (in main), and loop until answer is correct (according to return value of `generateQuestion`).

Every time you get a new answer (in loop), call `displayMessgae(false)`.
After the loop ended call `displayMessgae(true)`

This is my working code for this:

```
//For Random Generator
import java.util.Random;
//Uses a class Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assign6 
{
    public static int generateQuestion()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(9), y = x = r.nextInt(9);
        System.out.println("How much is " + x + " times " + y + "? ");
        return x * y;
    }
    public static void displayMessage(boolean isCorrect)
    {
        if (isCorrect)
            System.out.println("Good job! You got it right!");
        else
            System.out.println("You got it wrong, try again!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Scanner to Obtain Input from CW
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rightAnswer = 0;
        rightAnswer = generateQuestion();
        while (input.nextInt() != rightAnswer)
            displayMessage(false);
        displayMessage(true);

    }   
}
```

Comment: So you're calling the method in void by using: rightAnswer = generateQuestion(); right?

Comment: @guest_20 What do you mean?